# Using reduce() to get frequency of every character pair/triple in a string?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, mapreduce, reduce

I am supposed to complete this task in a functional manner, so no loops of any sort.

I already completed the task for finding the frequency of single characters. My code looks like this:

```
char_freq = {}

    def getcharfreq(char_freq, ch):
        char_freq[ch] = char_freq.get(ch, 0) + 1
        return char_freq

    # Get the frequencies of each character in the text
    functools.reduce(getcharfreq, text, char_freq)
```

where text is a long string of many characters. char_freq is a dictionary with the key being the character, and its value being its frequency in the text.

However, I'm not sure how to go about getting the character doubles, or triples, without using iteration first. For example, if my text were "I am Jimmy", the double would be:

"I ",

"am",

" J',

"im",

"my"

The triples would be every 3 characters at a time. It would be simple enough to iterate and add every 2 or 3 characters to a list, then pass that into reduce(). But since I can't iterate, I'm at somewhat of a loss as how to do this.

I'm pretty new to python in general and new to the concept of functional programming, so I apologize if the answer is simple. Further, if there is an entirely different method of doing this, that idea would be appreciated!

Comment: `getcharfreq` isn't really "functional" in the functional programming sense, it is purely for side-effects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know what you mean - I just know I'll be heavily penalized if I use any explicit loops, so I'm trying to find a work-around.

Comment: So what exactly are your constraints? You *have* to use `reduce`? Anyway, the most generic replacement for an iterative loop in functional programming is *recursion* which would be how you might have to generate all singles, pairs, and triples

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I suppose reduce isn't explicitly required, it was just mentioned: "use map/reduce". If I did it otherwise without iteration I'm sure it would be fine. Recursion, I see. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper function to produce all `n` sized groupings in a sequence.

```
def generate_n(seq, n, i, acc):
    if i >= len(seq):
        return acc
    else:
        acc.append(seq[i:i+n])
        return generate_n(seq, n, i + n, acc)
```

Note, it isn't purely functional, because I use `.append`, but without it, you'd have to use list concatenation, which is very inefficient here... In general, Python does not provide a lot of efficient structures to work with typical purely functional programming constructs. But to be "purely functional" you could use:

```
def generate_n(seq, n, i, acc):
    if i >= len(seq):
        return acc
    else:
        return generate_n(seq, n, i + n, acc + [seq[i:i+n]])
```

Note also, Python doesn't optimize tail recursion, so this solution is limited by your stack size (depths over about 1000 will get dodgy). But this would do for an exercise (and you would **never** write code like this in production Python).

Anyway, here it is in action:

```
In [1]: def generate_n(seq, n, i, acc):
   ...:     if i >= len(seq):
   ...:         return acc
   ...:     else:
   ...:         acc.append(seq[i:i+n])
   ...:         return generate_n(seq, n, i + n, acc)
   ...:

In [2]: generate_n("I am Jimmy", 2, 0, [])
Out[2]: ['I ', 'am', ' J', 'im', 'my']

In [3]: generate_n("I am Jimmy", 3, 0, [])
Out[3]: ['I a', 'm J', 'imm', 'y']

In [4]: generate_n("I am Jimmy", 1, 0, [])
Out[4]: ['I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'J', 'i', 'm', 'm', 'y']
```

The solution then boils down to counting for each n 1->3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use recursion ?  If so you can obtain the set of tuples of all lengths using a recursive function and the map() function to produce a list of counts:

```
def prefixes(s):
    return [s] + prefixes(s[:-1]) if s else []

def nTuples(s):
    return prefixes(s) + nTuples(s[1:]) if s else []

def tupleCounts(s):
    tuples = nTuples(s)
    return list( map(lambda t:(t,tuples.count(t)), set(tuples)) )
```

*Note that this counts overlapping tuples (e.g.. `ana` counted twice because it overlaps itself in `anana`)*

*if you only want 2-tuples and 3-tuples, you can add a filter on the assignment to the `tuples` variable in `tupleCounts()`*

output:

```
tupleCounts("banana")

[('a', 3),      ('ana', 2),   ('nan', 1),  ('nana', 1), ('bana', 1), 
 ('banana', 1), ('banan', 1), ('anan', 1), ('na', 2),   ('n', 2),
 ('an', 2),     ('ba', 1),    ('b', 1),    ('ban', 1),  ('anana', 1)]
```